# HTML template with dynamic resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make dynamic HTML elements which would be resized via jQuery. Here is the procedure I've used:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="top">top</div>
<div id="left">left</div>
<div id="right">right</div>
<div id="bottom">bottom</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #f5f7fa;
}

#top, #bottom, #left, #right {
    position: absolute;
}

#top {
    background-color: red;
}

#bottom {
    background-color: blue;
}

#left {
    background-color: orange;
}

#right {
    background-color: green;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT - jQuery**

```
$(function() {

    function ResizeObjects() {
        var margin = 10; // margin for LEFT and RIGHT panel

        var window = $(this);
        var body = $("body");
        var top = $("#top");
        var bottom = $("#bottom");
        var left = $("#left");
        var right = $("#right");

        // top panel
        top.css("top", 0);
        top.width(body.width());

        // bottom panel
        bottom.css("top", body.height()-bottom.height());
        bottom.width(body.width());

        // left panel
        left.css("top", top.height()+margin);
        left.css("left", margin);
        left.width( (body.width()/2)-(margin*1.5) );
        left.height( body.height()-top.height()-bottom.height()-(2*margin) );

        // right panel
        right.css("top", top.height()+margin);
        right.css("right", margin);
        right.width( (body.width()/2)-(margin*1.5) );
        right.height( body.height()-top.height()-bottom.height()-(2*margin) );
    }

    $(window).on("resize", function() {
        ResizeObjects();
    });

    ResizeObjects();

});
```

It seems it works somehow but if you try this on other devices like tablets with Safari browser or you can try to resize it in Chrome, you will see incorrect resize actions, especially with BOTTOM panel.

This example is based on idea that BODY is VIEWPORT (i believe this is name for whole visible space in any browser). Maybe this idea is wrong.

Whole example can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lyu1naqp/1/

Comment: if you are familiar with jquery you can easily use this plugin http://jqueryui.com/resizable/

Comment: Can't you just use CSS to do that?